# Issue with Spring MVC updating the model attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I just got stuck in a small issue in updating a form using spring mvc.

following is my code snippet

```
<form:form name="personInfo"  method="post"    modelAttribute="person"> 
<td class="empty"></td>
<td class="editablefields">Football:</td>
<td class="value">
<c:forEach  items="${person.gameList}" var="game" varStatus = "count">
<c:if test="${game.code == 'FB'}">
<form:textarea path="gameList[${count.index }].value" id="" />
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</td>
</form:form>
```

after submitting the form,game value is getting update in post method,but game.code is coming as null.

Pls explaing why this is happening?

Comment: You do not reference `game.code` in your form as a form input. Add the `gameList[${count.index }].code` as an hidden input field if you want to retrieve the value in the post handler

Comment: Thats is not necessary.I have done similar things before.Its getting updated properly.I have missed some thing in this case which i m not able to find

Answer (score 1):

Your markup needs to provide a mapping between `person` and its `code` attribute. Otherwise, the value in `code` won't get included in the HTTP request to your handler method. Try changing your loop to this:

```
<c:forEach  items="${person.gameList}" var="game" varStatus = "count">
  <c:if test="${game.code == 'FB'}">
    <form:textarea path="gameList[${count.index }].value" id="" />
    <form:hidden path="gameList[${count.index }].code" value="${game.code}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: `path="gameList[${count.index }].code"` may be better as `code` is a field of `game` and not of a `person`